# Tela para inserir valores

Tags: php, array, gui

Tenho este codigo e gostaria de criar um tela para usuario inserir valores e eles sejam inseridos nos seus respecitvos arrays, CREDITO (array a) e DEBITO (array b) e criar um botão executar para rodar o codigo e imprimir a resposta. Poderiam dar um help? Não entendo de ajax, javascript... Estou penando, imagino ser facil, mas não estou conseguindo.

Segue codigo.

```
<?php

$a = [];
$b = [];

$iguais = [];
$diferentes = [];
foreach($a as $item){
    $i = array_search($item, $b);
    if($i !== false){
        $iguais[] = '('. $item .', '. $b[$i] .')';
        unset($b[$i]);
    }else{
        $diferentes[] = $item;
    }
}

$d = [$b];
$e = [$diferentes];

$common = array_intersect( $diferentes, $b,$a); 

$diff2 = array_diff( $b, $common );
$diff3 = array_diff( $diferentes, $common );

$diferentes += $b;

echo "IGUAIS - ";
print_r($iguais);

echo "DEBITO - ";
print_r($diff3);

echo "SOMA(a) = ".array_sum($diff3)."\n";

echo "CREDITO - ";
print_r($diff2);

echo "SOMA(a) = ".array_sum($diff2)."\n";

?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas não parece ser necessário o uso de Javascript e muito menos Ajax. Apenas uma interface em HTML com dois INPUTs, o input credito e o input debito

Comment: Então, a interface HTML ta pronta eu não sei como faço pra receber os valores em credito e debito e eles serem inseridos no array a e no array b do codigo. Depois de inseridos eles roda o codigo e imprimi o resultado na tela. Conseguiu entender?

Comment: SIm, deu pra entender, é algo bem simples, vou fazer o exemplo

Comment: Muito obrigado @lvcs !

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, ja editei e exclui o outro comentario!

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer ir colocando dados no array e executar seu código, usei variáveis de sessão para armazenar os arrays mesmo quando a página é atualizada (só são apagados quando o navegador é fechado ou a sessão é destruída). Senti a necessidade de colocar 3 ações no sistema:

- Adicionar: apenas acrescenta o valor do input no seu array.
- Executar: executa o código da função.
- Encerrar: destrói a sessão e reseta os arrays.

É claro que o código pode ser melhorado, mas não vi necessidade de altera-lo mais. Embora não consegui entender o objetivo do mesmo.

```
 <!-- FORMULARIO DE ADICIONAR -->
<form action="#" method="post">
    <p><input name="number" placeholder="Crédito" type="text"></p>
    <p><input name="number" placeholder="Débito" type="text"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="ADICIONAR"></p>
</form>
<!-- FORMULARIO DE EXECUTAR -->
<form action="#" method="post">
    <p><input name="executa" type="hidden"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="EXECUTAR"></p>
</form>
<!-- FORMULARIO DE ENCERRAR -->
<form action="#" method="post">
    <p><input name="encerrar" type="hidden"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="ENCERRAR"></p>
</form>

<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 07/04/2016
 * Time: 16:31
 */
session_start();


// quando formulario de executar foi enviado
if(isset($_POST['executa']))
{
    // executa função de calcular
    calcula($_SESSION['credito'], $_SESSION['debito']);
}

// quando formulario de encerrar foi enviado
if(isset($_POST['encerrar']))
{
    // destroi arrays e a sessão
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
}

// quando formulario de adicionar foi enviado com o credito
if(isset($_POST['credito']))
{
    // adiciona valor do input no array
    array_push($_SESSION['credito'], $_POST['credito']);
}
else
{
    // quando for a primeira vez que entrou na pagina cria um array
    $_SESSION['credito'] = array();
}

// quando formulario de adicionar foi enviado com o debito
if(isset($_POST['debito']))
{
    // adiciona valor do input no array
    array_push($_SESSION['debito'], $_POST['debito']);
}
else
{
    // quando for a primeira vez que entrou na pagina cria um array
    $_SESSION['debito'] = array();
}

// exibe os arrays
var_dump($_SESSION);

// tranforme ie função para ficar légivel
function calcula($credito, $debito)
{
    $iguais = array();
    $diferentes = array();
    foreach($credito as $item){
        $i = array_search($item, $debito);
        if($i !== false){
            $iguais[] = '('. $item .', '. $debito[$i] .')';
            unset($debito[$i]);
        }else{
            $diferentes[] = $item;
        }
    }

    $common = array_intersect( $diferentes, $debito,$credito);

    $diff2 = array_diff( $debito, $common );
    $diff3 = array_diff( $diferentes, $common );

    $diferentes += $debito;

    echo "IGUAIS - ";
    print_r($iguais);

    echo "DEBITO - ";
    print_r($diff3);

    echo "SOMA(credito) = ".array_sum($diff3)."\n";

    echo "CREDITO - ";
    print_r($diff2);

    echo "SOMA(credito) = ".array_sum($diff2)."\n";

}

?>
```

Comment: Bom dia @lvcs , tentei executar aqui não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

No seu html, os inputs devem estar em uma tag form para funcionar. O que precisamos focar no html para que dê certo, são as propriedades "action" e "method" da tag form, a propriedade "name" das tags de input de texto (credito e debito) e a propriedade "type" do input EXECUTAR precisa estar definida como "submit".

Ou seja, a parte do form HTML ficaria assim:

```
<form action="endereco/do/seu/script.php" method="post">
   <label>DEBITO: </label><input type="text" name="debito" />
   <label>CREDITO: </label><input type="text" name="credito" />
   <input type="submit" value="EXECUTAR" />
</form>
```

E você pode buscar esses valores no seu suposto "script.php" alterando as 4 primeiras linhas do código para:

```
<?php
$a = [];
$b = [];
$a[] = $_POST['credito'];
$b[] = $_POST['debito'];
```